# which file is better to add jquery in modal form

Tags: jquery, wordpress, contact-form-7

I need to add some jquery on click, when contact form open's in modal window. I'm trying on console and it's working, but when I try to add on file, nothing changes.My code is

```
jQuery('.fl_box-menu-0 ').click(function(){
       var myClone = jQuery('.container_inner .title_subtitle_holder span').clone();
       jQuery(myClone).prependTo("#cboxContent form");  
   })
```

So I need copy a title from page header, and paste it in top of modal contact form. 
The form you can find here [word press web site](http://myrussiaonline.com/portfolio_page/13/)

and click contact me. When i try in console add

```
           var myClone = jQuery('.container_inner .title_subtitle_holder span').clone();
       jQuery(myClone).prependTo("#cboxContent form");
```

it is work and add title, but when i try add code in my file, nothing changes. So what I do wrong? I use contact form 7, and form lightbox for modal.
So now I'm looking the file, where to add jquery code, to make it is working.

Answer (score 0):

I would try this with a delegated event:

```
jQuery(document).on('click', '.fl_box-menu-0', function() {
   var myClone = jQuery('.container_inner .title_subtitle_holder span').clone();
   jQuery(myClone).prependTo("#cboxContent form");  
})
```

Reasons for using delegated events can be found [here](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/).

It's not clear if this is the issue, or only issue, but it if your click is not working like you except, and console is, then chances are that the click is not getting bound properly (dynamic element perhaps).

Comment: Can you also explain which file is better one to add jquery code? Because I also tried code like you post, but it's not working too for me...

Comment: @sanchahous Sorry, but I'm not great with Wordpress. Try my suggestion, and if it doesn't work then update your question about "which file is better".

Answer (score 0):

Solved using code:

```
    jQuery('.fl_box-menu-0').click(function(){
   jQuery('.order-data').html(
            jQuery('.title_subtitle_holder span').html()
            ); 
})
```